# change the color of specific rows every 10 seconds

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, rows

hello i am having a problem
i need to color in red some rows of a jtabl that get refreshed each 10 seconds.
also the set of rows to color changes. i update the set of rows to be changed to read then i need to change those in the table whenever found.
i tried the cell renderer of the table and coudn't.
if anyone can propose something i'm open to everything
would love to get some code as example.
any way of doing it would be welcome.
i tried playing wwith this funtion but i couldn't add the set of rows to change..
'''

```
 class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
     String separatedVariable;
     public MyCellRenderer(String separatedVariable) {
         this.separatedVariable = separatedVariable;
      }

      @Override
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
          Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
          c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
              JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
          if (separatedVariable.equals("YOUR VALUE TO GREEN")) {
              l.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

              return l;
          } else {
                     if (separatedValue.equals("YOUR VALUE TO YELLOW")) {
                          l.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                          return l;
                      } else if (separatedValue.equals("YOUR VALUE TO RED")) {
                          l.setBaground(Color.RED);
                          return l;
                      }
               }
              return c;
      }
}    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your own [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) to display the data. This renderer will be able to render a normal or red background depending on row data and the time. Then all you need is a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) to call your JTable's repaint() method.

Comment: i'm using gui builder in netbeans where can i define the table cell renderer ??
and will it repaint the whole frame or just the panel where the table is ?  and should i put it inside the timertask or what ?

Comment: I also love Netbeans and it's gui builder. However I am not sure how far you can go with just the gui builder. I'd simply add the TableCellRenderer to JTable after initComponents() has run.
As for how much is redrawn: The UI system actually decides. By calling the repaint method on a component you indicate this area should be redrawn. Therefore I'd do this call on the smallest component possible - that is JTable. The CellRenderer is used as flyweight pattern so it won't work on a smaller level.